# Area of the intersection of the region outside of a unit circle centered at origin and the region inside the unit circle centered at (1,0)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This problem was on my calculus final, and I had no idea how to set up the double integral to solve it.

Comment: This seems to be easier to calculate using good old cut-and-paste geometry than by setting up an integral.

Comment: Or, failing to follow Henning's suggestion, is using polar coordinates an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r=2\cos \theta$ is the circle centered at $(1,0)$ with radius $1$. (Why?)

$r=1$ is the unit circle.

Let's find the angles of intersections:

$\displaystyle 2 \cos \theta = 1 \implies \cos \theta = \frac 12 \implies \theta = \pm \frac \pi 3$

We want the area outside the unit circle $\implies r >1$

And the area inside the other circle $\implies r<2 \cos \theta$

$$A= \int_{- \frac \pi 3}^{\frac \pi 3} \int_1^{2\cos \theta}\underbrace{r}_{\text{Jacobian}} \ dr \ d \theta$$

Comment: Just want to add that the particularly nice function you get for the circle centered at (1,0), given in ThePortakal's answer, is exactly what makes this problem tractable and appropriate for an exam question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without integral: the intersection area of the two circles is formed by two symmetric equal parts, each corresponding to the area of a circular segment whose angle is $\frac {2 \pi}{3}$. The area of each of these two circular segments is $\frac {\pi}{3}-\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} $. So the area of the intersection of the region outside the first circle and the region  inside the second circle is

$$\pi- \left(\frac {2\pi}{3}-\frac {\sqrt {3}}{2} \right)= \frac {\pi}{3}+\frac {\sqrt {3}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using good old cut-and-paste geometry:

[image: cut-and-paste diagram goes here]

The straight vertical sides are $2\frac{\sqrt3}2$ tall and have a mutual distance of $1$.

Total area $\displaystyle \color{#380}{\frac{\pi}3} + \color{#003ce4}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}$.